# Kubuntu 17.04 install as VM fails

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, kde, initramfs

I am trying to install kubuntu as a VM on my win 7 laptop. for testing out. but it continue to fail with this error:

[image]

I even removed the USB from VM config. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go past this by:

1. create a VM without any USB HW.
2. select install OS later.
3. add path to .iso in CD/DVD section. (this will start install soon after launch).

this will load the .iso image, you will be able 'start' the installation manually.

enjoy !!!